# Typescript -> Babel sourcemaps using webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs

Copy paste from ts-loader issues as it might be more appropriate here:

How to pass the typescript sourcemaps to babel so the end sourcemap point to the original file and not the compiled typescript one?

Here's an example of my dev settings:

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "gulpfile.js", "webpack.config.js", "server.js"]
}
```

`webpack.dev.js`:

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  devtool: "eval",
  entry: [
    "webpack-hot-middleware/client",
    "./src/app/index",
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "app.js",
    publicPath: "/static/"
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      'window.fetch': 'exports?self.fetch!whatwg-fetch'
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    noParse: [
      /\/sinon.js/
    ],
    preLoaders: [{
      test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
      loader: "tslint",
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader!ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `source-map-loader` for webpack. Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./app.ts",
    output: {
        filename: "./bundle.js",
    },

    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        extensions: ["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".js"]
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            // ts -> ES6 -> babel -> ES5
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loaders: ["babel-loader", "ts-loader"] }
        ],

        preLoaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    }
};
```

And `tsconfig.js`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

[image: source in chrome devtools]

Comment: I could not get this to work for Babel 7 and Webpack 4. The source maps generated reflect the transpiled output from the TypeScript compiler instead of the source files.

Answer (score 2):

Old issue, but if anyone else runs across this try setting devtool to a different value in the webpack config like:

`devtool: 'inline-cheap-module-source-map'`

Expected Output Per Setting:
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#root